# Flutter Fire Type cast AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapShot<Map<String, dynamic>>> to List<dynamic>?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Cloud Firestore Database and Flutter.

My Implementation

```
AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot
```

After snapshot has data

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    final List<dynamic> _products = snapshot.data!docs[0].data() as List<dynamic>
}
```

Value of the expression `snapshot.data.docs[0].data()` using debugging I found it not null.
It is of the type `_InternalLinkedHashMap`

Comment: Please share more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `snapshot.data.docs[0].data()` shows up as a `_InternalLinkedHashMap` it is a `Map` and not a `List`, so you can't cast it to a list.

It sounds like you want:

```
snapshot.data.docs[0].data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

If you get another error on that case, I recommend searching for the error message - as most of the common conversions have been covered before.